Why light have gravitational lensing?
I was reading about light in a book there it was there that light is not a physical quantity, light has no mass as photons are more and more smaller then atoms. Then how does gravity affect the path of light? or it was written wrong.

"light is not a physical quantity" is not the good way to put it.

"there it was there that light is not a physical quantity" What does that mean?

Gravity is due to spacetime itself being curved. The light is just trying to move in the straightest possible path that it can take. On a curved spacetime, this straightest possible path looks curved to us. So gravity has to affect light propagation. This should not be too difficult to understand.

Have a look at How can gravity affect light? I think this is the same question you are asking.

This is an extremely poor question as it shows no research effort at all.

Gravity affects anything that carries energy. Photon has energy, therefore gravity attracts it (all men are mortal, therefore Socrates is mortal).
If it is the purported masslessness of photon that confuses you, then know that photon only has zero rest mass. If, on the other hand, you define mass as $m=E/c^2$ ("dynamic mass"), then it is obviously nonzero even for a photon and the paradox is no more.
If you are still not convinced, then refer to Einstin's GR equation and see that gravity couples to the stress-energy tensor, not mass.

didn't understand the line " then it is obviously nonzero even for a photon and the paradox is no more". please explain.

@ShivanshMaheshwari The energy $E$ of a photon is nonzero, therefore its relativistic mass $m = \frac E {c^2}$ is non zero, therefore its path is affected by gravity.

In fact even things like lines and curves that are just mathematical concepts are affected by gravity - gravity is more accurately the curvature of space rather than a force applying to objects.

thank you I did understand it now
